# Which flag can be used for "convert some code to another programming language"?

Tags: support, flags, close-reasons

Today I found a question where the OP wants someone to convert some code to another programming language.

I want to flag that question to close it, but I can't find a flag like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is as clear cut as you describe, I would probably vote to close as Too Broad. However, this is a very generic question so that isn't going to apply to all questions that in one way or another fit into that metric.

You can have a question like the following.

> I have X code and I want the same code in Y language.

This is just a request for code, there is no attempt to solve the problem themselves and it shows a general lack of research. That is too broad for Stack Overflow.

One caveat: If the amount of code being translated is very small, then it could very well be on-topic, for example [preg_match_all JS equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983798/preg-match-all-js-equivalent). While not a great example, it isn't too broad. The user is simply asking for how to do something very simple in one language in another. In cases like that, depending on the tag, there might (and probably is) a duplicate target somewhere.

Now, if the question was

> I have X code and I'm trying to make Y code, but the foobar isn't connecting to the farbizzle. What am I doing wrong?

And the code the they included in their question demonstrated the intent and problem in a minimal and complete fashion, then it probably wouldn't be too broad for Stack Overflow.

One Caveat: It can still be too broad of a problem for Stack Overflow, for any number of reasons.

As always, posts should be judged on a post by post basis  with attention to the merits of the post itself. There will always be exceptions to every rule and ultimately your vote is your own to do with as you see fit.

If you're ever unsure, check with other users in chat rooms where users with close votes gather and ask them what they would do, for example [The SO Close Vote Reviewers room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers).

Comment: +1 for "Farbizzle", by far my favourite thingamabob!